# Get class name of $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `$("#notifications_list, .opt_notifications_parent")` and then i am using `$(this)`. Now I need to check if `$(this)` is the first selector or the second. 
How can i do that?

I tried something like this, but will not work:

```
if ($(this) == 'opt_notifications_parent'){
    console.log("test");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
if ($(this).hasClass('opt_notifications_parent'))
```

or [is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) (which is a more expensive operation, so use hasClass)

```
if ($(this).is('.opt_notifications_parent'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `is()`

```
if($(this).is('.opt_notifications_parent') )
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, the easiest way is:

```
if ($(this).is('#notifications_list')) {
  // ...
} else if ($(this).is('.opt_notifications_parent')) {
  // ...
}
```

Or, you can do it the JavaScript way, which should be a bit quicker:

```
if (this.id == 'notifications_list') {
  // ...
} else if (-1 !== Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.classList, 'opt_notifications_parent') {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Careful checking the ID first as the element in question may have both ID and class

Comment: @Phil: It still could have both if we check the other way around. I was mostly demonstrating tests themselves; it depends on the specific use case and OP's desired application logic.

Comment: Yes but if the branching logic centres around whether or not the element has the class (which seems to be the most likely case), that should be in the `if` instead of the `else if`

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside an event closure, you can do like this:

```
$("#notifications_list, .opt_notifications_parent").on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is('#notifications_list')) {
        // first selector clicked.
    } else {
        // other selector clicked.
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem with this is, the element may be both `<a id="notifications_list" class="opt_notifications_parent">`

Comment: @Phil right. So I'd suggest to use either classes of ids only within single selector.